# How do I get the PID of a process spawned with Perl's system function?

Tags: perl, system, pid

I'm writing a Perl script (say `script.pl`) that calls another script `newscript.pl`. I want to get the PIDs of both the scripts in `script.pl` only. I can get the PID of `script.pl` by using following code

```
my $pid = Unix::PID->new();
my @p = $pid->get_pidof( $pid->get_command($$), 1 );
```

After this I call `system` to execute `newscript.pl`

```
system("perl newscript.pl");
```

I want to capture the PID generated by this `newscript.pl` in `script.pl`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the time `system` returns, the spawned process will have already exited, leaving its pid as an interesting historical reference—useful for log analysis, for example.

> **`system LIST`**
>   **`system PROGRAM LIST`**
>
> Does exactly the same thing as `exec LIST`, except that a `fork` is done first *and the parent process waits for the child process to exit* …

If you want the pids of both `script.pl` and `newscript.pl`, `fork` and manage their lifetimes yourself. With more specific information about the problem you’re tackling, we could give you more specific suggestions.

---

To block other instances of a program, a common technique is to use the operating system’s facility for cooperative locking: at startup, attempt to lock a certain file. If successful, your program knows it’s the only one. Otherwise, another process already has the lock, so the new process exits. See below for an example.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl qw/ :flock /;
use File::Basename;
use POSIX qw/ strftime /;

$0 = basename $0;

my $LOCK = "$ENV{HOME}/.lock-$0";

sub logmsg {
  my($msg) = @_;
  my $t = strftime "%F %T", localtime time;
  warn "$0: $t - $$ - $msg\n";
}

sub take_lock {
  open my $fh, ">", $LOCK or die "$0: open $LOCK: $!";

  unless (flock $fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) {
    logmsg "failed to lock $LOCK; exiting.";
    exit 1;
  }

  $fh;
}

my $token = take_lock;
logmsg "processing...";
sleep 2 * 60;
logmsg "done.";
```

Note that you must keep the filehandle returned from `take_lock` open while control is inside your [critical section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section). The code above treats it as an opaque token. When your program exits, Perl closes the filehandle, which releases the lock automatically. What you don’t want to do is call `take_lock` in void context because that would discard your lock.

Comment: My script.pl does the task of scheduling other other scripts like newscript.pl and lot of other scripts. I can not go about scheduling them directly in cron and hence thought of making this parent script which would act as scheduler. Now , There may be a case when the scheduled script is repeated as i get the script names from MySql databse, I dont want the script which is already running to execute again and hence I was thinking if i could capture the PIDs of scheduled scripts, I can check on the basis of these Pids and avoid simultaneous run of the same script.  Thanks a Ton for your help

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without using fork ?

Comment: Use `flock()` if you need exclusiveness. `use Fcntl qw(:flock); flock ($lockfd, LOCK_NB|LOCK_EX) or die "Same script already going"; # ...` Note that $lockfd is a file descriptor and not filename (you have to open it prior to flock).

Answer (score 10):

The process number of the current process is in [`$$`](http://p3rl.org/var#%24%24). Use [open3](http://p3rl.org/IPC::Open3) instead of `system` to receive the process number of the child process.